# QGIS geometry editing listener

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, vertices, event-listener, qgsrubberband

I would like to know if it's ever possible to make a listener on geometry editing.
What I know so far is a `geometryChanged` signal that can be used in listening to layer when its feature's geometry is edited. I use it to print the area of an object when it is modified.

But it makes a signal only when editing is stopped, i.e. if I move a vertex, a signal will be called only after vertex is placed.

My goal is to set a listener on vertex move. I didn't find an appropriate signal in `QgsVectorLayer` and thought that it's something about `QgsRubberBand` or `QgsVertexMarker`.

When vertex or even line is moving, new hashed lines are appearing, so I thought they may be Polyline `QgsRubberBand`.

[image]

```
for item in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
    iname = type(item).__name__
    if iname == 'QgsRubberBand':
        print(item.asGeometry())
```

But when I look through items in scene and try to convert it to geometry, I got empty shapes like:

```
Output:
    <QgsGeometry: null>
    <QgsGeometry: MultiPoint ()>
    <QgsGeometry: Polygon ()>
```

I also tried to get `QgsVertexMarker` the same way and to what they have by methods `data()` or `x()` and `y()` but results were not even close to  what I had in geometry. Data was `None` and both x and y were more like a coordinates of a global canvas as they changed when I move canvas.

Here is a full code I use right now to see area changes:

```
screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
size = screen.size()
w, h = size.width(), size.height()
class area_printer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        """Set GUI 
        """
        self.setGeometry(w/2-200, h/2+0, 320, 20)

        self.setWindowTitle('Dynamic area window')
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.current_layer = None

        self.txt_area = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lbl_layer = QLabel()

        self.grid.addWidget(self.lbl_layer, 0, 1, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.txt_area, 1, 1, 1, 3)
        
        iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(self.lyr_changed)
        
        self.lyr_changed()
        self.show()
    
    def lyr_changed(self):
        if self.current_layer:
            self.current_layer.geometryChanged.disconnect(self.print_area)
            self.current_layer.selectionChanged.disconnect(self.print_selected_area)
        self.current_layer = iface.activeLayer()
        
        self.current_layer.geometryChanged.connect(self.print_area)
        self.current_layer.selectionChanged.connect(self.print_selected_area)
        return

    def print_area(self, fid, geom):
        self.lbl_layer.setText(self.current_layer.name())
        self.txt_area.setText('{}'.format(round(geom.area(),5))) 
        return

    def print_selected_area(self):        
        self.lbl_layer.setText(self.current_layer.name())
        self.lbl_layer.setText(self.current_layer.name())
        s_geom = sum([f.geometry().area() for f in self.current_layer.getSelectedFeatures()])
        self.txt_area.setText('{}'.format(round(s_geom,5))) 
        return


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.current_layer.geometryChanged.disconnect(self.print_area)
        iface.currentLayerChanged.disconnect(self.lyr_changed)
        self.current_layer.selectionChanged.connect(self.print_selected_area)
        return

app = area_printer()
```